# In Ubuntu 13.04, can I add more wallpapers to the collections Ubuntu already has?

Tags: unity, desktop-background

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04, and I noticed there are several excellent wallpapers, but I'd wish to add my own in a sort of collection similar to those it has that have an auto-changing cappability. I tried using Wallch and DesktopNova, both look cool, but neither works, dunno why... But I suppose it shouldn't be so hard to make my own images rotable, or is it?

So... Can I save my images in some special folder to see them there? Is it possible to add a folder instead of just one image at the time, so they rotate?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Variety.

> Variety is a wallpaper changer for Ubuntu which is featureful, yet
>   slim and very easy to use. It can automatically download wallpapers
>   from various online sources, allows rotating them on a regular
>   interval or on demand, and provides easy to use ways to separate the
>   great images from the junk.

To install Variety, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peterlevi/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install variety
```

Once installed, search variety in dash, and run it.  Once opened, adjust the settings to your liking,  I added the `/home/user_name/pictures`, and used my own, plus the original backgrounds folder, and it works OK.

[image]